# pip in virtualenv cannot find ctypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

Before creating a virtual environment, `pip` is working:

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

However, `pip` does not work within a virtual environment.

```
$ virtualenv env
$ env/bin/pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip import pep425tags
  File "/system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/pep425tags.py", line 9, in <module>
    import ctypes
ImportError: No module named ctypes
```

I am able to `import ctypes` in my system Python

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 22 2014, 11:24:51) 
[GCC Intel(R) C++ gcc 4.1 mode] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>>
```

but not in the virtual environment Python

```
$ env/bin/python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 22 2014, 11:24:51) 
[GCC Intel(R) C++ gcc 4.1 mode] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ctypes
>>>
```

I don't have much experience with `virtualenv`.
What steps should I take to debug the problem?
Thanks!

My operating system CentOS 6.6.
The system uses environment modules to manage different versions of software.

Comment: I'm not sure if on creation of a virtualenv, it activates the virtualenv at the same time. If not, make sure to run `source env/bin/activate` before doing anything, as this will change your $PATH. Then you can call `pip` without the preceding `env/bin`. Although I suspect this won't solve your issue... just a thought.

Comment: This did not change the result.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found some time to look into this. So since I can't reproduce this issue on my system (Ubuntu 16.10), I tried to simulate the problem to see what happens. But, here's one step you can take to debug this.

### Background

1. `virtualenv` uses the your system's python, thus, since you have the `ctypes` module in your system python, you should be able to find it in your `virtualenv` python.
2. On Ubuntu 16.10, the `ctypes` module of the system python2.7 is located in `/usr/lib/python2.7`. Not sure where this is for CentOS - you need to figure that out.

## Debugging

### Check `sys.path`

Launch your `virtualenv` python.

```
filip$ source testenv/bin/activate
(testenv) filip$ python
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160914] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Print out the `sys.path` variable (if you can actually import `sys` in the first place)

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/filip/virEnvTestDir/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

See if the directory where `ctypes` is on your system is in that list. If not, add it with `sys.path.append("/path/to/ctypes/")`.

### `--system-site-packages` option

As @pterojacktyl pointed out:

In case `ctypes` is in your system python's `site-packages` directory. Creation of the virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` option

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages env
```

will make sure to link your `virtualenv` python to your system's third-party packages (which may include `ctypes` in this case).

### Experiment on Ubuntu 16.10 - (Optional read)

To test this out, I launched my `virtualenv` python and removed the directory where `ctypes` was located. Naturally, it raised an `ImportError`.

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint as p

# define the paths that we should remove from sys.path
remove = ["/usr/lib/python2.7"]

# remove all the specified paths
sys.path = [path for path in sys.path if path not in remove]

import ctypes # raises ImportError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ctypes # raises ImportError
ImportError: No module named ctypes
```

Comment: You're right! The directory of `ctypes` is not in `sys.path`.

My `sys.path` contains `/system/software/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `/system/software/linux-x86_64/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7` but `ctypes` is located at `/system/software/linux-x86_64/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ctypes/`. What determines `sys.path` in a `virtualenv`?

I have found that pip does seem to work in the virtual environment if I create it with `--system-site-packages`. Will this have any undesired effects?

Comment: @pterojacktyl Interesting. `ctypes` is part of the python standard library and `.../site-packages` is usually for third-party software. So I don't know why `ctypes` is in `.../site-packages`. Adding the `--system-site-packages` option on creation of the `virtualenv` will simply include any third-party modules your system python uses. I would not expect this to cause any issues and would suggest you use that for the time being. The question of how `sys.path` is determined by `virtualenv` is an interesting one I'll have to look into at some point.

Comment: @pterojacktyl But `virtualenv`s behaviour of not including the `../site-packages` directory by default is expected. What's weird here is that `ctypes` is in that directory in the first place.

Comment: @pterojacktyl You're welcome! Glad we both learned something.